# getting a nav bar and flexslider on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar and flexslider on the same page but the nav bar is messing up the flexslider. How can I get the stylings to separate from each other?
I tried making the nav bar go under 1 class but it doesnt seem to work. Please help!

this is the style at the top of the page:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
</script>




<title>St. Anthony</title>
<style>

.flexslider {
 width:700px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
}


li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}


li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: goldenrod;
    background: firebrick;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover a {
    background: #FF0000;
}


li:hover ul a {
    background: firebrick;
    color: #goldenrod;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #000000;
    color: goldenrod;
}


li ul {
    display: none;
}


li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}


li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}


.show-menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #19c589;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
}


input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}



@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}

}

section {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    }
nav {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    padding:2px;
    }
div.opener {
 font-size:120%;
 text-align:center;
}

</style>
</head>
```

Comment: Not really sure I can tell what you're seeing, but have you tried clearing  your floats?

Comment: Could you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please